# Can not find JSXElement in babel parser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I'm writing a plugin to modify the code of JSX files, but the babel parser just can not find any JSXElement in the code. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
import babel from "@babel/core";
import * as t from "@babel/types";

const code = "export const TagItem = (props)=> { return <div><h1>{props.tag.text}</h1></div>}";

const output = babel.transformSync(code, {
  sourceType: "module",
  plugins: [
  "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
    function myCustomPlugin() {
      return {
        visitor: {
          Identifier(path) {
            if (t.isJSXElement(path.node)) {
              console.log("JSXElement found");
            }
          },
        },
      };
    },
  ],
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer on my own. The `ast` output is turned off by default for performance issues. Just set it to `true` in the options, as follows:

```
import babel from "@babel/core";
import * as t from "@babel/types";

const code = "export const TagItem = (props)=> { return <div><h1>{props.tag.text}</h1></div>}";

const output = babel.transformSync(code, {
  sourceType: "module",
  ast: true,
  plugins: [
  "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
    function myCustomPlugin() {
      return {
        visitor: {
          Identifier(path) {
            if (t.isJSXElement(path.node)) {
              console.log("JSXElement found");
            }
          },
        },
      };
    },
  ],
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```